# Alternative to Windows Snipping Tool for Mac OSX

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, keyboard, screen-capture, switching

Is there something like the Windows Snipping Tool for OSX?

For those, who don't know about the tool, it's an easy to use software to take snapshot of any portion of screen, and is really useful in various situations.

Comment: can you please avoid using apple.stackexchange.com as a replacement for basic googling?

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX I understand your concern, but I wouldn't expect to find the topvoted answer below, on Google. Moreover, I'm sure others also found it helpful.

Comment: First hit for "screenshot mac os x" on google is a page with extensive info on the shortcuts and their uses

Comment: I did Google it, must have used different keywords but all I found was a bunch of third party softwares...

Comment: Oh well, next person to google this question will find this answer.

Comment: Snip is great! Thanks for sharing!!! Having a difficult time from a Windows user to a MAC user...

Comment: @AMomchilov basic googling brought me here though. :) lol

Answer (score 89, accepted):

There is now a blog entry about **[Taking Screenshots in a Snap](http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/02/taking-screenshots-is-a-snap/)**.

---

It's built into Mac OS.

- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> captures the whole screen
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> captures a custom rectangle 
  (click and drag over the screen region you want to capture)
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> then <kbd>space</kbd> captures a specific window (move the mouse cursor over the desired window, then click)

Press <kbd>esc</kbd> to cancel.

Screenshots are **saved onto your Desktop** and timestamped.

Holding <kbd>control</kbd> in addition to any of the sequences above causes the image to be copied instead of saved to the desktop.

By default the image format is **png**. However, you can change the format by typing in the **Terminal**:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture type image_format
killall SystemUIServer
```

Where `image_format` is one of `jpg`, `tiff`, `pdf`, `png`, `bmp` or `pict` (among others). If you omit the second line, you will need to log out and in again for the change to take effect.

The settings for the shortcuts in the system preferences are located at:
[System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts → Screen Shots](http://cl.ly/Clxq/Bildschirmfoto%202011-12-21%20um%2007.41.00.png)

The MacOS X application that enables screenshots is called Grab. It is located at `/Applications/Utilities/Grab.app`

Comment: awesome! the only problem being as a beginner Mac user I'm already overwhelmed with so many shortcuts!!! One more to remember! :D
and I guess after the clicking and dragging the region is in memory so where do I paste it now? need to install an image editing program?

Comment: The screen shot should produce an image file (a .png?) on your Desktop. The built-in application Preview should allow you to open it.

Comment: @DavidRouse is right. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Note the heavy use of "built in" :)

Comment: Thanks guys! Yes, the captured image is present on the desktop. :)

Comment: Holding control in addition to the above shortcuts copies the desired selection to clipboard (like print screen on windows) rather than saving an image file to the desktop

Comment: Yes, this can be found in **[``System Preferences->Keyboard->Keyboard Shortcuts->Screen Shots``](http://cl.ly/Clxq/Bildschirmfoto%202011-12-21%20um%2007.41.00.png)**

Comment: http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/02/taking-screenshots-is-a-snap/

Comment: +1 for @timothymh 's link, which shows cool actions like **Tools > Adjust Size...** and `^+⌘+A` for adding arrows...

Comment: Note also if you want to prevent the drop shadow from showing up in window screenshots (with the spacebar) also hold down **option**

Comment: I don't think you are very familiar with the windows snipping tool, or if you are then you clearly completely overlooked that the snipping tool has a feature of copying to the clipboard which I don't see in your alternatives.

Comment: Be great if a single key can copy the selection and save the selection and also have ink selected when opening the save from the preview notification. Really miss being able to copy-paste and annotate in one action like on windows. Need to build a mod.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to remember the shortcut keys, you can also use the built-in **Preview** app.

Just launch Preview, then from the menu, select **File**, **Take Screen Shot**, then choose

- **From Selection** - you will get a crosshair to drag
- **From Window** - you will get to choose which window to grab
- **From Entire Screen** - it will give a countdown first, so that you can get back to whatever app you want to take a picture of

It will then display the screenshot in Preview, and you can save, copy, paste, crop, etc. from there.

Comment: thanks for this - if you automate it, it behaves exactly like snipping tool (I put details 4 answers below)

Comment: Preview's Tools > Annotate menu provides the functionality I was missing from the snipping tool, namely the ability to highlight and otherwise draw on the screenshot.

Answer (score 6):

Macworld magazine's senior editor Dan Frakes just posted a very good short video tutorial (with show transcript) about the screenshot features of Mac OS X.  This includes how to use the Grab app from the Utilities folder.   The video is at:
 http://www.macworld.com/article/164123/2011/12/mac_os_x_screenshot_secrets.html.
His show description:
"Mac OS X makes it easy to take screenshots—images of your screen or objects on it. But even veteran Mac users are often unaware of the many options available for getting the perfect screenshot. Here's a quick look at these underused options."

Comment: The Grab app seems to be forgotten. Search for screen dump apps for OSX and it is almost never mentioned. I see no reason why.

Answer (score 2):

If you also need editing capabilities (e.g. like Windows Paint or however it's called these days), [Skitch](http://www.skitch.com/) is a good add-on (and it's free).

Answer (score 1):

Easycrop, or start with the insanely great (and free) SnapNDrag, from Yellow Mug — http://www.yellowmug.com/

Answer (score 1):

You may like [Snip](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/snip/id512505421?mt=12), I used it for a while and I found it fantastic. You can download it from Mac App Store for free

Comment: id be scared of anything made by Tencent.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the most convenient way to snapshot on Mac is by pressing keyboard shortcuts, however, this traditional method lacks additional features like making annotations, uploading images online for sharing, etc. For this purposes, you can make use of professional Mac screenshot tools that features the same function as Snipping Tool.

**Grab** - A built-in screenshot tool on Mac that enables you to capture anything you see on screen.

**Skitch** - Easy tool that allows for capturing, annotating and sharing screenshots / images.

**Jing** - An effective screen capturing program that works for recording screen and taking screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard Maestro can drive Preview to behave exactly like snipping tool

F13 (in the same place as PrintScreen on Windows)

Open Preview.app

Select menu File/Take Screen Shot/From Selection