# Take a screenshot of a QuickTime movie frame?

Tags: quicktime

I'm trying to export a screenshot of a part of a video in QuickTime Player 10.

How can I save a freeze frame capture from a QuickTime movie?

The saved image should be only the single video frame, not including the QuickTime Player window's chrome or controls.

I can't find a screenshot menu item in the Export menu...

[image]

Answer (score 48):

QuickTime solution:

1. Pause the QuickTime video on the still frame you want as an image, then hit `Edit > Copy` or <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.
2. Open the Preview app and select `File > New from Clipboard` or <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.

Comment: Odd that that works, but it does!

Comment: Works for me on macOS Sierra (10.12.6)

Comment: Wow, unexpected but still working in macOS Ventura 13.0.1 

Comment: Genius! You can even paste (Cmd+V) the image directly into Canva or other image applications you're working with.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work anymore in macOS Monterey (12.5)

Comment: definitely still working in latest Monterey :)

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work on Ventura 13.3.1

Comment: I never had issues with this pre-Ventura, but Ventura 13.4: it *sometimes* works... You might have to play/pause, scrub around a bit before it will let you cmd+C. I don't know what the magic combination is but just try to play around with it a bit and it should eventually let you copy the frame. Weird.

Comment: I had to play/pause to get it to work

Answer (score 8):

If you can't get this to work in your version of QuickTime you'll need another tool.

[VLC](https://www.videolan.org) [Freeware] can snapshot either on the fly or when paused with  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>S</kbd>  & generally runs rings round Quicktime as a player.

[image]

Note, because of its popularity, there are scam sites primed for unsuspecting prey.
VLC's domain is **videolan.org**

Comment: So, to conclude, it can't be done in Quicktime?

Comment: Not as far as I’m aware.