# What's the equivalent of windows explorer?

Tags: finder, switching

The documentation says that Finder replaces windows explorer.  However I have gone to my home directory in a terminal and created a directory with

```
mkdir temp
```

How can I browse this directory using Finder?  At the moment I cannot see it at all.

Comment: This works as expected for me (I'm using Mac OS X Lion). If I `CD ~` (to the home directory) and enter `mkdir temp`, a new temp folder appears in Finder. One way you can view the contents of the Home Folder in Finder is by clicking on the Desktop background and then pressing the `Shift+⌘+H` key combination. Are you confusing the Desktop with the Home Folder? Which documentation are you referring too?

Comment: Just to be precise, the Finder doesn't replace Windows Explorer; Windows Explorer was Microsoft's attempt to duplicate the functionality of the Finder. The Finder was a feature on the Mac in 1984, long before Windows Explorer.

Comment: @Daniel, these kids today just don't understand. :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- You can access the finder via the Dock:

  [image]
- When in the terminal, you can open the current directory in the terminal via:

  `open .`

Here's a finder window. I've created the directory `~/temp` like you said.

[image]

You can also <kbd>⌘</kbd>-click the info icon at the very top to see the path:

[image]

Comment: what software do you use to make screenshots with arrows like that?

Comment: @Michiel I make the screenshots using the [build-in feature](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/33907/13414) of the OS. Then I edit the pictures using the free app [Skitch](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/skitch/id425955336?mt=12). It's very easy to use.

Comment: Preview can also make some arrows on screen shots as well, but Skitch makes it much nicer.

Comment: For screen shots, I use SnagIt for Mac, from Techsmith.